# I have two form tags in the same style sheet and am having trouble styling

Tags: html, css

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/90/)

On the link above, there are two form tags, one at the very beginning and one at the very end of the style sheet. The one I am using for the profile page is the very last one in the style sheet.  It has a class of `.first1` to make it specific, but somehow the CSS is getting confused between the two tags. What can I do to let the CSS know I mean the last tag as opposed to the first form tag?

Comment: Sorry, why did this earn a downvote? Just due to poor wording of the question?

Comment: I will re-word it better later on.

Comment: Voted up to counter the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're getting at is needing to remove the space between the element and class name so change

```
 form .first1
```

to

```
form.first1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `form .first1` which means: "an element of class `first1` within an element of type `form`"..

Try changing it to `form.first1` which means: "an element of type `form` with class `first1`"

The space makes all the difference.

Comment: fello, you should accept jnpcl's answer if it solved your question.